# Angular NavigationStart - Stop navigation conditionally

Tags: angular, angular-router, navigationstart

I have a case where I want to stop the navigation based on a condition in the component. Please look at the code below

```
if(val instanceof NavigationStart){
    if(on some condition) {
        // Stop the navigation from here
    }
}
```

I already have CanDeactivate which serves some other purpose of checking. In this case, I do it at the component level with the data I have currently.

Is there any way that I can use this NavigationStart to achieve my requirement.

Please help me. Thank you...

Comment: You can use `canDeactivate` to guard from navigating off of the component, for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52044306/how-to-add-candeactivate-functionality-in-component . Lmk if it helped or not.

Comment: There are some more ways to stop navigation, which is part of routing. We probably need more context