# Perform http request before switching to next route

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-routing, angular-router

I want to perform a post request when navigating away from the page to any other route.

I have tried using:

```
  this.subscriptionGrade = router.events
      .pipe(filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationStart))
      .pipe(
        concatMap(() => {
          return this.submitScore();
        })
      )
      .subscribe((res) => {
        this.snackBar.openSnackBar("Score submitted", "");
      });


  submitScore() {
    const score = { score: this.scoreForm.get("score").value };
    if (this.scoreForm.get("score").value) {
      return this.learningContentService.gradeAssignment(
        this.selectedAttempt,
        score
      );
    } else {
      return of(null);
    }
  }
```

This performs the http reuquest but switches to next route before a response is recieved from the http request and the request is getting cancelled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use canDeactivate on this route and check if the http call is successful or no

```
export interface CanComponentDeactivate {
 canDeactivate: () => Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean;
}

...

@Injectable()
class CanDeactivateComponent implements CanDeactivate<CanComponentDeactivate>{
 constructor() {}
 canDeactivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
 let data= route.data.data;
 return this.service.post(url, data)
   .pipe(
     map(response => response.status === 'success'),
     catchError(error => of(false))
   );
 }
}
```

your route

```
{
 path: 'yourRoute',
 component: Component,
 canActivate: [CanDeactivateComponent ],
 data: { data: {...}}
}
```

Comment: what if its a post request?

Comment: same thing, post or get will not change anything

Comment: i was following the scotch link you posted

Comment: yes it's a simple example, i've updated my answer to get data

Comment: there im giving the same code and wrinting a method canDeactivate inside the component i want to check and giving guard in the route .. Im getting error invalida canActivate guard..

Comment: If using the method in the link ,there is no need for passing data inside the guard since logic is checked inside component itself

Comment: Have you checked the scotch link example?

Comment: I cannot pass data in route like this because the data is from a form value field

Comment: hmmm i didn't know that it's from a form

Comment: ok i think the found the problem ,. in the route you have to pass canDeactivate: [CanDeactivateComponent].. Not canActivate

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52044306/how-to-add-candeactivate-functionality-in-component